# Method with 2 entities as Generic C#

Tags: c#, list, generics

I need your help. I'm trying to reuse this method in differents parts of a project but I like to make it generic. Any ideas?

```
    public static List<Entity1> Method1(List<AssociationEntity> searchlist)
    {
        List<Entity1> list = new List<Entity1>();
        Entity1 entity;
        foreach (AssociationEntity item in searchlist)
        {
            entity = new Entity();
            entity.ID = item.ID;
            entity.NAME = item.NAME;
            list.Add(entity);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Or maybe can someone could simplify this in an easier way, my problem is that I have a List type of a class which is composed by to entities and I want to convert it in a list of one of the entities

I mean,

There is an existing method which load info from database and collect it into a List but AssociationEntity is composed by 2 entities

**Entity1(ID, Name)

Entity2(ID, Name)

AssociationEntity (Entity1, Entity2)**

```
List<AssociationEntity>
```

so if I want to acccess to the ID from the Entity1, I would do this

```
List[0].Entity1.ID
```

but imagine that I want a direct list of **Entity1**. That's why I made a Method1 to perform a loop and do it manually but if there is a function with linq or collection methods that would be awesome. If not, as I said at the beginning make Method1 as generic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One thing that isn't clear here - which I think is the cause of the two differing answers at the moment. You say `AssociationEntity` consists (i.e., has two properties?) of `Entity1` and `Entity2`. That is, in your loop, `item` should have those two properties. But you access `item.ID` rather than `item.Entity1.ID`. Maybe a more concrete example would help. As it stands, @Daniel's answer is based on your *description* of `AssociationEntity`, returning references to the `Entity1` property, while Jeffery's answer is based on your *use* of it, returning a new `Entity1` instance.

Comment: Thank you all you guys for answering. Daniel did what I wanted concretely. Besides that I wanted to make the Method1 generic of type T in order to pass different entities because I wanted to see also how can I use a generic method with 2 objects to evaluate but the answer simplified my life. Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use LINQ, do this:

```
List<Entity1> Ent1List = searchlist.Select(item => item.Entity1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could shorten that quite a bit using LINQ:

```
public static List<Entity1> Method1(List<AssociationEntity> searchlist)
{
    return searchlist.Select(x => new Entity1() { entity.ID = x.ID, entity.NAME = x.NAME }).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even create an extension method based on [Jeffery Khan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17557697/209259):

```
public static class AssociationEntityExtensions
{
  public static List<Entity1> ToEntityList(this List<AssociationEntity> searchlist)
  {
    return searchlist.Select(x => new Entity1() 
      { 
        entity.ID = x.ID, 
        entity.NAME = x.NAME     
      })
      .ToList();
  } 
}
```

Usage:

```
List<AssociationEntity> mysearchlist = new List<AssociationEntity>();
List<Entity1> myentities = mysearchlist.ToEntityList();
```